# How to Find Single Row Records from Two Rows Data with AttTime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have query to find Records in to single records from two rows with  First AttTime  and Last AttTime using SQL Server 2005

My AttLog Table Structure is:

```
EnrollNo    Int
AttDate     DateTime
AttMonth    Int
AttDay      Int
AttYear     Int
AttTime     Varchar
```

Current output:

```
EnrollNo     AttDate               AttMonth   AttDay   AttYear   AttTime
405  2011-03-09 09:59:00.000       9          3        2011      9:59     
405  2011-03-09 18:40:00.000       9          3           2011   18:40
```

Desired output:

```
EnrollNo     AttDate               AttMonth   AttDay   AttYear   FirstTime   Last Time  
405  2011-03-09 09:59:00.000        9        3          2011      9:59        18:40
```

Comment: SQL Server 2010? both `c#` and `VB.net` tags? The question seems to be database related and no `sql` tag! Please be specific, while asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are grouping records with same EnrollNo, you should use [aggregate functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

```
  SELECT EnrollNo, Min(AttDate), Min(AttMonth), Min(AttDay), Min(AttYear), Min(AttTime) as FirstTime, Max(AttTime) as LastTime    
  FROM AttLog
  GROUP BY EnrollNo
```

Comment: At a guess, this should probably be grouped by the date part of AttDate as well.  But that's just inference as the OP is unclear on such points.